# "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" when trying to access MySite

Tags: 2013, my-site, social

I'm receiving the error in the title when trying to access my personal site on the MySite Collection. I can fix this by adding "Full Read" permissions for "Everyone" on the entire web app but I'm not sure if this is secure or a good idea on the web app that hosts the MySite Collection.

With the farm account, I can get onto the site no problem and check permissions for my personal account and see it has no permissions without this setting.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked if search shows and relevant information? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=this+site+been+shared+you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try creating a permission policy for your web application on Central Administration followingly:

1. On Central Administration, navigate to *Application Management* -> Under *Web Applications*: *Manage web applications*
2. Select your My Site -web application by clicking it, and open *Permission Policy*
3. Click *Add Permission Policy Level*
4. Enter at least the Name for your Permission Policy
5. Select following Permissions:
6. `Create Subsites  -  Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and Document Workspace sites.`
7. `View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.`
8. `Browse User Information  -  View information about users of the Web site.`
9. `Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.`
10. Leave other parts unmarket and click *Save*
11. Make sure your My Site -web application is selected and open *User Policy*
12. Click *Add Users*, and on first view leave *Zones:* `(All zones)` selected, then click *Next >*
13. On *Choose Users* -part click *Browse* (the catalogue type of icon). Click *All Users* and select *Everyone* activated. Press *Add ->* and *OK*
14. On *Choose Permissions*, select the Permission Policy you recently created, and finally click *Finish*

In case you haven't already followed the TechNet's guide [Configure My Sites in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362(v=office.15).aspx), you should from now on :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out on the guide, moe. I appreciate your help. Accepted.

Comment: At point 12, this is where you are supposed to add Active Directory groups and service accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, found this [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ecab4f1a-6191-47e5-973d-e6bab0ccf202/sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you?forum=sharepointadmin) (worked for me):

> If you have credential for account who has rights on site then, by simply hitting below URL, you can have prompt to login prompt.
>
> http:/serverurl/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that account the site was running on did not have enough permission in Active Directory.
Solution: run ApplicationPool under my own account.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this feature enabled: "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" at site collection level - Deactivate it. - Because, this prevents limited access users from getting Form pages!

Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you-sharepoint-2013.html#ixzz66SjMs4nc

Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you-sharepoint-2013.html#ixzz66SjMsGhm

Answer (score -1):

check your permissions & try to run by system account that will help.